# Possessive Pronouns Doubt

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, possessive-pronouns

Possessive case pronouns have a s without an apostrophe; so is this correct "It's hers watch". If not why and also in which sentences can " hers" be used.

Comment: You don’t have *doubt*.  You have a question. You’re also confusing possessive pronouns with possessive determiners.  This is very basic grammar.  Please see [ell.se].

Comment: @tchrist: Re: "confusing possessive pronouns with possessive determiners": The term "possessive determiner" is relatively new -- they always used to be called "possessive pronouns" (or *sometimes* "possessive adjectives") -- and certain modern authorities, such as CGEL, argue that they are in fact pronouns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possessive pronouns *that* end in the sound /-s/ or /-z/, spell it <-s> with no apostrophe (with the exception of *whose* and *one's*).

However, not all possessive pronouns end in the sound /-s/ or /-z/.

In the case of *her(s)*, we use *her* before a noun, and *hers* on its own:

> - *This is her watch.*
> - *This watch is hers.*
> - *Hers is the red one.*

It is not grammatical to replace *her* with *hers* or vice versa.

Comment: Some examples of possessive pronouns with /s/ or /z/ sounds you mentioned would be deeply appreciated. Thanks for the help dude

Comment: @RandomCodemonkey: Ending in /s/: *its*. Ending in /z/: *his*, *hers*, *ours*, *yours*, *theirs*.